# Accessing service from within src/groovy

Tags: grails

I've built some custom marshallers and I'm trying to access the messages service. I have the following code.

**resources.groovy**

```
customObjectMarshallers(CustomObjectMarshallers){
    marshallers = [
        new PersonMarshaller(),
        new DepartmentMarshaller(),
        new ErrorsMarshaller()
    ]
}
```

**CustomObjectMarshallers**

```
class CustomObjectMarshallers {
    List marshallers = []

    def register(){
        marshallers.each {
            it.register()
        }
    }
}
```

**ErrorsMarshaller**

```
class ErrorsMarshaller {

    @Autowired
    def MessageSource messageSource

    void register(){

        JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(FieldError){ FieldError fieldError ->

            def pMap = [:]

            fieldError.properties.each { prop, val ->
                println 'prop ' + prop
                if( prop == 'rejected_value' || prop == 'arguments' || prop == 'class' || prop == 'codes' || prop == 'code' || prop == 'bindingFailure') {
                    return
                } else if(prop == 'defaultMessage') {
                    pMap[prop] = messageSource.getMessage(val, fieldError, Locale.US)
                } else {
                    pMap[prop] = MarshallerUtils.cleanPropertyValue(val)
                }               
            }

            return pMap
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following exception

Cannot invoke method getMessage() on null object. Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getMessage() on null object
    at org.hri.leaverequest.marshaller.ErrorsMarshaller$_register_closure1_closure2.doCall(ErrorsMarshaller.groovy:26)
    at org.hri.leaverequest.marshaller.ErrorsMarshaller$_register_closure1.doCall(ErrorsMarshaller.groovy:21)
    at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:202)
    at grails.converters.JSON.convertAnother(JSON.java:162)
    at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:202)
    at grails.converters.JSON.render(JSON.java:134)
    at org.hri.leaverequest.CalendarController.processRequest(CalendarController.groovy:154)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:198)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:49)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Comment: What version of Grails? Did you configure scanning of those packages?

Comment: @JoshuaMoore version 2.4, I don't know what that means to configure scanning of those packages.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of Grails (2.x in this case) you may need to include the packages in "Spring bean scanning". Look in your `Config.groovy` and add them:

```
// packages to include in Spring bean scanning
grails.spring.bean.packages = ['com.example.my.package.here']
```

Comment: I'm assuming I continue keeping my existing code the same and just add my src/groovy package to grails.spring.bean.packages? If that is correct, I have done that with no success. I'm still experiencing the same error.

Comment: Remove `def` from your property injection.

Comment: Same error Cannot invoke method getMessage() on null object. Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getMessage() on null object
 at org.hri.leaverequest.marshaller.ErrorsMarshaller$_register_closure1_closure2.doCall(ErrorsMarshaller.groovy:26)
 at org.hri.leaverequest.marshaller.ErrorsMarshaller$_register_closure1.doCall(ErrorsMarshaller.groovy:21)

Comment: I'd try a `clean` and see if that clears the error, otherwise I'm lost because I do the same thing without issue.

Comment: hmm, it doesn't have anything to do with how I'm registering my objects within CustomObjectMarshaller?

Comment: Actually that's it. (: I spaced out. Since you are `new`ing the instances they don't do any DI. You can do your own DI through constructor injection. e.g. `new PersonMarshaller(messageSource: messageSource)` ... I need more coffee apparently.

Comment: I don't need to use  ref('messageSource') ?

Comment: Yes, you do, since it's a bean.

Comment: Looks like I'm close then, I just need to resolve this exception and I think this will finally work. org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '<messageSource>' with class 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.RuntimeB
eanReference' to class 'org.springframework.context.MessageSource'
 at resources$_run_closure1_closure4.doCall(resources.groovy:39)
 at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeBeanDefiningMethod(BeanBuilder.java:703)
 at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeMethod(BeanBuilder.java:561)
 at resources$_run_closure1.doCall(resources.groovy:29)
 at

Comment: Remove the `@Autowired` and change it to `def messageSource`. I bet that will resolve the issue.